# Status code 500 Paperclip amazon s3 connection refused - (Connection refused - connect(2) for "bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" port 443

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Paperclip can't seem to connect to my amazon s3 bucket instance  it gives this error -

```
*** Exception Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Rack application object (Connection refused - connect(2) for "bucket-images-test.s3.amazonaws.com" port 443)
```

My production.rb looks like this:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => 'bucket-images',
          :access_key_id => 'accesskey',
          :secret_access_key => 'seceretkey',
           :host_name => 's3-website-us-east-1'
      },
      :default_url => "/missing.png",
      :path => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
      :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
  }
```

I'm using:

- paperclip version 4.2.0
- aws-sdk version 1.63
- aws-sdk-resources version 2

Comment: Shouldn't `:url` be set to `":s3_domain_url"`?

Comment: your talking about the old s3 gem

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the gems and also the iptables
Gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.5.8'
gem 'aws-sdk-resources '~> 2'
```

also i was blocking port 443 so i had to change the iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```